# Install Node-Red service for Everyone

Tags: node-red

how can I install Node-Red on a Windows system as a service that runs automatically on boot, for every user?

It is already installed and running, but it's only accessible for one user.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, you don't.

The slightly longer answer,

It's probably worth pointing a few things out first:

- A single Node-RED instance will only ever run one flow, there is no concept of multiple user accessing a single instance and each having access to their own canvas to create their own flows.
- While a single instance does support authenticating different users, this is only for control of read-only/read-write access to the single running flow.
- Each instance of Node-RED will require a separate port to listen on.

If you want to provide a Node-RED instance to multiple users through a single frontend then you need to look building a solution with a frontend proxy for something like Docker which will run a new container with Node-RED instance per user. There are comercial PaaS providers like [FRED](https://fred.sensetecnic.com/) from Sensetecnic that use this pattern to provide Node-RED instances to thousands of users.

There have been a couple of projects to build similar systems, that you should be able to find on the Node-RED forum. For the best effect you should probably be using a database as the backend flow storage, rather than a mounted volume/filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Follow links on official site

https://nodered.org/docs/faq/starting-node-red-on-boot

I used this one
https://gist.github.com/dceejay/576b4847f0a17dc066db
and it worked

Comment: That is still only going to run 1 instance, not an instance per user as the OP asked.